Substitution method of integration in python without use of external packages
I am trying to calculate the integral of the attached image integral from 0 to infinite of 1 / ((1 + x) * sqrt(x))dx. I know this value is equal to pi. I must also print out the result to the precision of 8 digits past the decimal point. I also have to subtract my answer from numpy.pi and print the difference to the 15 digits passed the decimal point. The difference is known at: -0.000000000000099. I have got a decent start but the difference is not quite right and my pi is only accurate to the 7 decimal places.

I am not very savvy with python this is my first real time trying to learn it and it is tough to say the least.
import numpy as np

# Define the function after substitution
def integrand(u):
    return 1 / ((1 + u) * np.sqrt(u))

# Numerical integration using the trapezoidal rule for the integral from 0 to 1
def integrate_substitution(a, b, n):
    h = (b - a) / n
    integral = 0.5 * (integrand(a) + integrand(b))
    for i in range(1, n):
        integral += integrand(a + i * h)
    integral *= h
    return integral

# Set parameters for numerical integration
a = 1e-8       # Lower bound, close to 0 to avoid division by zero
b = 1 - 1e-8   # Upper bound, close to 1
n = 1000000    # Number of intervals

# Compute the integral from 0 to 1 and multiply by 2 for the full integral
result = 2 * integrate_substitution(a, b, n)

# Print the result to 8 decimal places
print(f"Pi is {result:.8f}")

# Calculate the difference from numpy's pi to 15 decimal places
difference = result - np.pi
print(f"Difference from numpy.pi is: {difference:.15f}")

This is the code I had. My output is:
Pi is 3.14864591
Difference from numpy.pi is: 0.007053257301424
I am expecting it to be:
Pi is 3.14159265
Difference from numpy.pi is: -0.000000000000099

Might be worth asking this on the math stack exchange instead https://math.stackexchange.com/

You aren't doing a “substitution”, despite your title and code. If you DID do a substitution you would be able to remove the problem of dividing by 0 at x=0. As it stands, your omission of the area near 0 gives an error of about 2.sqrt(x), or 0.0002. There is no need to put an upper bound deliberately less than 1, because there are no problems with the integrand at x=1. (Your image doesn't show the upper bound at 1.)
If you want to do a substitution then substitute x=u^2 and remove the singularity at x=0. Better still, substitute x=tan(v)^2 and do the integral analytically.
